# Printing after specific string

Tags: sed, grep

I have a text file, containing the following text lines

```
AAA http://hello.world.com/12345/11.*aa*
AAB AAC http://hello.world.com/12346/11.*aa*
```

How can I print url for line starting with AAA?

```
cat file.txt | tr -d ' ' | grep -i 'AAA' | cut -f2 -d':'
```

Above would only display `//hello.world.com/12345/11.*aa*` but I could of course harcode **http:** when I expand variable it's just a messy way of doing things.

Comment: Why would you think of `tr -d ' ' | ... | cut -f2 -d':'` when you want to select everything after a space and keep the part before the `:`? Is there something about the problem you haven't told us yet?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sed -n 's/^AAA *//p' file
http://hello.world.com/12345/11.*aa*
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply with **awk** (assuming that *url* is the last item of each line):

```
awk '/^AAA/{ print $NF }' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the criteria is that the URL is always after the last space in the line (at least for lines starting with AAA):

```
$: echo "AAA http://hello.world.com/12345/11.*aa*" | grep -i "^AAA" | sed 's/^.* //g'
http://hello.world.com/12345/11.*aa*
```

The sed bit matches all text from the beginning of the line up to the last space and removes it.

The echo is just an example I tested with. You would use:

```
grep -i "^AAA" file.txt | sed 's/^.* //g'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -oP "^AAA.*\Khttp.*" file
```

Output:

```
http://hello.world.com/12345/11.*aa*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cat file.txt | grep "^AAA" | rev | cut -d ' ' -f1 | rev
```

Output: `http://hello.world.com/12345/11.*aa*`

**Details:**

`cat file.txt`: Print the content of the file.

`grep "^AAA"`: Keep only line begining by "AAA".

`rev`: Reverse the characters of each lines.

`cut -d ' ' -f1`: Split each line using space as delimiter and keep the first column.

`rev`: Reverse the characters of each lines.